Use 1 6 7 8 (all numbers) to equal 2
Create an equation using 1, 6, 7 and 8 to equal 2.
Can use brackets, plus, minus, subtract, multiply.

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

Is concatenation allowed, and can a number be used more than once?

Every number has to be used once. And only once. Thanks for your help!

Thank you. You don't mention 'divide'. Is division allowed? And did you make this puzzle?


 impossible


 1 6 7 8 mod 7 is 1 -1 0 1
 so to make 2, we need 2 mod 7.  We need to add or subtract at least once, and the addition has to involve something that is not 0 mod 7.

 To make 2 mod 7, there is either 1 + 1 or 1 - -1 (or their negation). The other two numbers could then only make -1, 0, or 1 mod 7: you can either add 0 or multiply by +- 1.

 1 + 1 --> 1 + 8 = 9
 1 - -1 --> 1 - 6 = -5 or 8 - 6 = 2

 In the 1 + 1 case, only 0 and -1 (7 and 6) are left.
 Multiplying by +- 1 doesn't work, and making 0 is only possible by 7 * 6.

 In the 1 - -1 case, 7 and either 1 or 8 are left.
 Adding 0: 7 * 1 only works with 1 - 6, repeating 1 (the 7 * 1 can just be 7 but the 8 can't be placed anywhere in 7 + 1 - 6), 7 * 8 doesn't work
 Multiplying by +- 1: 7 - 8 only works with 8 - 6, repeating 8


Partial answer for when division is allowed:

 ((8 + 6) / 7) x 1

Detailing that gives:



 8 + 6 = 14




 14 / 7 = 2




 2 x 1 = 2




A silly answer:

 If you write the numbers in Roman numerals
I VI VII VIII
 and reorganise the letters
V - V + V - III + II - II
 the sum is II or $2$.

